# Visual Studio 2015 when using [Display(var = "var")] then declaring var on the next line get error

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Visual 2015 - sometimes get the following error when using [Display

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'PN' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The first one fails the next two work, after that they all fail.  Seems they do not recognize the variable name as the failure occurs with the ones that have the squiggly red line underneath.

```
    [Display(PN = "PN")]
    public string PN { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CCA Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(ShortName = "CCA Short Name")]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    [Display(CardDesignation = "Card Designation")]
    public string CardDesignation { get; set; }
```

Comment: That error is completely correct.  `DisplayAttribute` has no such properties; your code is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Name` in the Display attribute is not the name of the property. It is a property on DisplayAttribute. So your code should look like

```
[Display(Name = "Card Designation")]
public string CardDesignation { get; set; }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I am a newbie at visual studio and C#.  Now if I can just find a an example to connect to access database with 2015.  The server works, but want the table data in my application.